# On Hortonworks Sandbox 2.4, Spark use of SQLServer driver results in "No Suitable Driver Found"

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, apache-spark, hortonworks-data-platform, apache-zeppelin

HDP version 2.4

I am trying to write to a SQL Server database via the Microsoft SQL Server JDBC driver sqljdbc41.jar.  I'm executing the following in Zeppelin:

```
val foo = sqlContext.jdbc("jdbc:sqlserver://X;databaseName=X;user=X;password=X", "X")
```

[image]

which yields the "no suitable driver found" error.

This is a common issue and so far I've tried the following, without luck, based on various remedies I've found through the interwebs:

- add the full path to the JAR for the following properties in spark-defaults.conf:

> ```
> spark.driver.extraClassPath
> spark.executor.extraClassPath
> spark.files
> ```

- add SPARK_CLASSPATH with the same JAR path in spark_env.sh

After making these changes I've stopped and started the Spark service through the Ambari interface, and I do see the changes reflected in both the Ambari portal and within the configuration files on the VM.

I did notice that many posts indicate you still have to provide the jar on the classpath when running spark-submit, but I'm accessing through Zeppelin, so not sure how that applies.

Answer (score 0):

Try using JDBC Interpreter with Zeppelin 0.6.0 and configure MySQL driver.

[image: JDBC Interpreter Config]

You can also try to follow http://thedataist.com/tutorial-using-apache-zeppelin-with-mysql/

Perhaps you just need to change the connection string as this post suggests.

Comment: this doesn't apply since I'm not trying to use JDBC from Zeppelin directly - it's more of a Spark issue I think